# execute delete,sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ",",while i

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to remove duplicate data from the database,
This statement can be executed in navicat.

```sql
delete from Proxy_Main 
where (Proxy_Main.ip,Proxy_Main.port) 
       in (select ip,port from Proxy_Main group by ip,port 
           having count(*) > 1) 
   and rowid not in (select min(rowid) from Proxy_Main 
                     group by ip,port having count(*)>1)
```

error info:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ",":
>   syntax error [SQL: 'delete from Proxy_Main where
>   (Proxy_Main.ip,Proxy_Main.port) in (select ip,port from Proxy_Main
>   group by ip,port having count(*) > 1) and rowid not in (select
>   min(rowid) from Proxy_Main group by ip,port having count(*)>1)']
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```html
   @staticmethod
    def execute(sql):
        conn = engine.connect()
        conn.execute(sql)
        conn.close()

    @staticmethod
    def deduplication():
         SqlHelper.execute('delete from Proxy_Main where (Proxy_Main.ip,Proxy_Main.port) in (select ip,port from Proxy_Main group by ip,port having count(*) > 1) and rowid not in (select min(rowid) from Proxy_Main group by ip,port having count(*)>1)')
```

Comment: You might have to double check on sqlite's site but I have a feeling that it doesn't support the tuple `(a, b) in (select a, b from ...)` style comparisons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row value comparison as being attempted in `IN` clause is only available in [SQLite 3.15+](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html). As mentioned at very bottom of linked docs page:

> Row values were added to SQLite version 3.15.0 (2016-10-14). Attempts to use row values in prior versions of SQLite will generate syntax errors.

Check your version (`SELECT sqlite_version();`). Upgrade as needed since your query *does* work with an updated version (run the example [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qwpvzAw5eAepmYdJrVgKj/0)).

Alternatively, consider a more ANSI-SQL solution (i.e., portable across RDBMS's) using an aggregate join subquery:

```sql
DELETE FROM Proxy_Main 
WHERE rowid IN
   (SELECT p.rowid
    FROM Proxy_Main p
    INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT ip, port, MIN(rowid) As min_id 
          FROM Proxy_Main 
          GROUP BY ip, port
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS agg
    ON p.ip = agg.ip AND p.port = agg.port
    AND p.rowid <> agg.min_id);
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wDqpXvdSVn7v2Xfg3NYi1w/0) *(press Run at top)*

---

Do note you can pass multi-line queries in Python with triple quote strings.

```
@staticmethod
def deduplication():
    sql = """DELETE FROM Proxy_Main 
             WHERE rowid IN
                (SELECT p.rowid
                 FROM Proxy_Main p
                 INNER JOIN 
                      (SELECT ip, port, MIN(rowid) As min_id 
                       FROM Proxy_Main 
                       GROUP BY ip, port
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS agg
                 ON p.ip = agg.ip AND p.port = agg.port
                 AND p.rowid <> agg.min_id);"""

    SqlHelper.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Curious what helped: new query or updating SQLite?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the reply, I use the SQL statement you said above，Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

In airflow.cfg file ( version 2.0 ) set
max_num_rendered_ti_fields_per_task = -1

This worked for me.